# Changing version to Swift 1.2 rather than Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, version

I am using Xcode version 7.2.1 with Swift 2.1, but I need to use Swift 1.2 to school projects. How can I do this task?

Comment: Xcode 6.4 comes with Swift 1.2, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your teacher what version of Xcode they're using and then go to "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer Tools" and find that version of Xcode (search for "Xcode" and you'll see all of the recent versions) and install it. Then use that old version of Xcode instead of the version you're currently using.

Comment: @aegeantale once you find that out, here's the URL to pull old versions: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/